# Proving that 1/3 has no finite decimal representation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, decimal-expansion

There is a problem where i need to prove that 1/3 has no finite decimal representation

Here's my proof, can someone tell me if its valid?

**Proof**

Lets assume there is a decimal representation for $\frac{1}{3}$, Therefore:

$ \exists n,b \in \mathbb{N} $ : $ (\frac{b}{10^n}=\frac{1}{3}$) $ \land (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{10^k}=\frac{1}{3})$

By the theorem: $\frac{1}{3} = \frac{b}{10^n} $

b = $\frac{10^n}{3}$ = $\frac{(2 \times 5)^n}{3}$

Thats a contradiction ($b \notin \mathbb{N}$), Since that fraction is irreducible (Both 2,5,3 are prime numbers).

Is my proof valid? If not, Can someone explain what's wrong with it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say $0.33333...$ is a perfectly fine decimal representation of $1/3$.

Comment: Yes it looks Ok. But you should maybe write "cannot be ***finitely*** represented by decimal number system" or something.

Comment: It is fine, though you can immediately write $1/3=b/10^n$ where $n$ is the number of decimals.

Comment: Yeah, I meant finite decimal representation, And 0.333... isn't a finite representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is almost correct, but you should not write $2.5$ when what you mean is $2\times5$.

And, yes, $\frac{(2\times5)^n}3=\frac{2^n5^n}3$, which is indeed an irreducible fraction. You didn't say *why* it is irreducible, but it is easy: since $3$ is prime and $3\nmid2^n5^n$, $3$ and $2^n5^n$ are coprime and therefore, yes, the fraction is irreducible.

Comment: A . is a perfectly common multiplication symbol several places in the world. For instance, it appears on occasion on the brown paper of Numberphile. One should still probably be careful with using it, though. Particularly when writing to an international audience like here in this site. I personally think $\times$ looks almost as bad, since I was raised to use $\cdot$, and that's just the way it is.

Comment: I know that, but in this instance it is ambiguous, and therefore it should be avoided. It's like using the notation $|\cdot|$ for the determinant. No problem for $n\times n$ matrics with $n>1$, but would you really write that $|-1|=-1$? It is correct, nonetheless…

Comment: On the topic of 2.5 to represent the multiplication of 2 times 5, it is incredibly ambiguous whether you mean 2 and 5 tenths or if you mean 2 times 5, with most people leaning to the first interpretation.  If you are stuck using only the symbols directly available on a keyboard, `*` is more commonly used to notate multiplication.  We do have access to MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here, giving us access to better alternatives such as `\cdot` and `\times`, both being common symbols used for multiplication in literature.  **TLDR:** 2.5, bad, 2*5 acceptable,  $2\cdot 5$ and $2\times 5$ good.

Comment: As for the pros and cons of using `\cdot` versus `\times`, again both are quite common in my experience.  `\times` runs the risk of being confused for a variable $x$ depending on the handwriting or font, while `\cdot` runs the risk of being confused for a decimal point.  They key for handwriting these is to center them vertically.  For that reason, I tend to prefer `\times` when it is purely arithmetic such as $2\times 5$ while I tend to prefer `\cdot` when it is purely algebraic such as $x\cdot y$, of course never switching notations mid-problem.